# Number of intermediates and transition states in hydration of given alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, hydrocarbons

> What is the number of transition states and intermediates formed in the following reaction?
>
> [image]

**My thought:**

1. First the alkene extracts $\ce {H^+}$ from the acid to form a **carbocation**. This step involves a transition state and the formation of an intermediate which is a secondary carbocation.
2. Next, we have an alkyl shift to this carbon, resulting in a ring expansion. The carbocation is now tertiary. Again, involving an intermediate and a transition state.
3. Finally $\ce{H2O}$ attacks on the tertiary carbocation. We again get a transition state and intermediate here.
4. A proton now leaves, which involves a transition state. The product now forms.

So I think there will be 4 transition states and 3 intermediates, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think that’s a good brain-and-paper theoretical analysis. A computational chemist would probably use this as a starting point.

Comment: Haha I had no idea that it was even slightly correct. I got it all by fluke, I think.